# Fabric.js canvas boundary detection

Tags: fabricjs

I'm new to Fabric.js.

I'd like to show a movable/resizable rectangle inside a canvas, but restrict user actions so that it cannot be moved/enlarged outside the canvas.

Is there a simple way to set these constraints? do I nee to detect the canvas boundary manually?

Comment: Yes, you can use "object:moving", "object:scaling", etc. events and constrain object position/dimensions accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so I have to get the bounding box (I've seen a BB example on the website), and make a few checks on it. It would nice if this constraint could be applied to the objects as an editable property ...

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dams/4T4JT/2/ How do I validate/invalidate a move inside onChange function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After object scaled or dragged, it will find the location. If the location beyond the boundary, it will revert the object to the previous state.

```
canvas.on('object:modified', function (e) {
   var obj = e.target;
    var rect = obj.getBoundingRect();

    if (rect.left < 0
        || rect.top < 0
        || rect.left + rect.width > canvas.getWidth()
        || rect.top + rect.height > canvas.getHeight()) {
        if (obj.getAngle() != obj.originalState.angle) {
            obj.setAngle(obj.originalState.angle);
        }
        else {
            obj.setTop(obj.originalState.top);
            obj.setLeft(obj.originalState.left);
            obj.setScaleX(obj.originalState.scaleX);
            obj.setScaleY(obj.originalState.scaleY);
        }
        obj.setCoords();
    } 
    });
```

For more example: http://sett.ociweb.com/sett/settJun2014.html